# Don't understand why I am getting this - 'Error: Value storage corrupted: negative offset'

Tags: java, xpath, intellij-idea

I just started using IntelliJ-IDEA, and I don't know if the problem resides with the IDE or not. I'm assuming not but I have no idea. I've spent quite a lot of time googling this error to no avail.

The error comes about at compile time. The weird thing is that I returned my code to the way it was before the error was showing up and it is still being thrown. Here is a little bit of my code that I believe is causing the problem. But I think it might be something besides my code.

```
import org.joda.xpath.XPath;

private XPath componentXPath;
private List list;
this.componentXPath = XPath.newInstance("(//rss/channel/item)");
Document doc = jiraAdapter.fetch("path to XML file");
list = componentXPath.selectNodes(doc);
```

The `componentXPath.selctNodes(doc)` is somehow causing the problem. If i remove this line, then it compiles fine, but I need to get a list of all the nodes to work with.

The error shows up in the messages pane: `Error: Value storage corrupted: negative offset`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IDEA version do you use? Try File | Invalidate Caches and then rebuild the project.